# Why first item of char double pointer is corrupting

Tags: c, pointers

In my program i don't understand where i'm making mistake. The first pointer buffer is corrupting the rest of buffer is fine. Gcc version is "gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3".
Please help...
Thanks.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  char **buff;

  int i = 0;
  buff = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *));

  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    buff[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 32);
    sprintf(buff[i], "test %d",i); 
  }

  printf("address of buff: %u\naddress of buff[0]: %u\n", buff, buff[0]);
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    printf("%d: %u:%s\n", i, buff[i], buff[i]); 
  } 

}
```

My Output:

```
address of buff: 21930000
address of buff[0]: 21930032
0: 21930032:��N
1: 21930080:test 1
2: 21930128:test 2
3: 21930176:test 3
4: 21930224:test 4
5: 21930272:test 5
6: 21930320:test 6
7: 21930368:test 7
8: 21930416:test 8
9: 21930464:test 9
```

Comment: `buff = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *));` creates memory for one `char*` pointer, but then you store 10 of them there. It should be `malloc(sizeof(char *) * 10);`.

Comment: This is a punishment from the compiler because you're casting the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: @duDE; Unfortunately it worked for you.

Comment: In addition, there's another undefined behavior: you are printing a pointer with `%u`, which is not for pointers but for `unsigned int`s.

Answer (score 0):

You are overrunning your buffer:

```
buff = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *)); // a single char* is allocated
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    buff[i] // when i is 1 it's out of bounds
```

Bang you're dead.  Undefined behavior.